# Created CA when there are no logs

Tags: contract-deployment, receipts

Sometimes there are TX that create a Contract but its receipt doesn't contain any logs, for example:

https://basescan.org/tx/0xb9d3c35f59132b6172812834a7540de7c49fdb8ff207700f15b5eba3be609808

returns this receipt:

```
AttributeDict({'blockHash': HexBytes('0x1138ae2eb5666a7e1bd74167f9b9383b7fd3165d2f6f3e6caf488089b72f5bbb'), 'blockNumber': 12551970, 'contractAddress': '0xc927930371Dd11Dc895Be3b9060d81729a58D4Ac', 'cumulativeGasUsed': 4503658, 'effectiveGasPrice': 122425195, 'from': '0x2806f7C26d98b5cF96469008a36fE8fDb6e55555', 'gasUsed': 110009, 'l1Fee': '0x746e23e32a8', 'l1GasPrice': '0x539af0b64', 'l1GasUsed': '0x1758', 'logs': [], 'logsBloom': HexBytes('0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'), 'status': 1, 'to': None, 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0xb9d3c35f59132b6172812834a7540de7c49fdb8ff207700f15b5eba3be609808'), 'transactionIndex': 33, 'type': '0x2'})
```

How can the CA be retrived in these cases?

Comment: What are you using for contract deployment (like ethers.js, hardhat, foundry, etc.) ?

Answer (score 0):

The contract address are deterministic. They do not need to be retrieved, but they can be calculated from the deployer address + nonce + contract bytecode.

If you are deploying with `web3.py` when you deploy a contract using the deploy function, it will give you the address of a newly deployed contract.

If it is a third party smart contract deploying contracts using CREATE2 refer to the developer documentation of this contract.